# Angular 5: Obtaining form input value whether changed or not

Tags: forms, angular5

How can I pass to `onNext()` the form's input value of the control named "Category1"? When the form is changed the value is passed but when the user doesn't change the value isn't. I need the value always passed. How do I do this?

```
<div class="app-form container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="button-left float-left">
                <button (click)="onPrevious('tab-empinfo')">Previous</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="button-right float-right">
                <button 
                (click)="onNext('tab-selection', {
                         form: 'category', 
                         data: {category: formCategory.value['Category1']}})">
                Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h4>Category</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form #formCategory="ngForm">
                <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let input of categorySelection; let i = index">
                    <choice *ngIf="input.type == 'choice'" name="Category{{ i + 1 }}" ngModel
                            [multiple]="input.multiple" [question]="input.question" [answers]="input.answers"></choice>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<pre>
    {{ formCategory.value | json }}
</pre>
```

Please see screen shot:

[image]

Comment: What a disappointment not a single comment, really?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `input` tag instead of `choice`. Set the `[(ngmodel)]` to a property of your container, e.g. `category1` and use the same name for each input. It does not need to match the property name, I arbitrarily set it to be `category1`. Set `category1` property to the default value. The component's category1 property value will initialize one of the radio button to be set. Use the `category1` property in your on click method parameter.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yq5w2y?file=app/app.component.ts for a working example.

```html
<div class="app-form container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="button-left float-left">
                <button (click)="onPrevious('tab-empinfo')">Previous</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="button-right float-right">
                <button 
                (click)="onNext('tab-selection', {
                         form: 'category', 
                         data: {category: category1}})">
                Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h4>Category</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let input of categorySelection">
                  <input  type="radio" *ngIf="input.type == 'radio'" [(ngModel)]="category1" name="category1" value="{{input.answer}}" > {{input.answer}}
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
----
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  categorySelection = [{type: 'radio', answer: "who"}, {type: 'radio', answer: "what"}];
  category1 = "who";
  result;
  onPrevious(data: string) {
    this.result = data;
  }
  onNext(x, data: any): any {
    this.result = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also the `#formCategory="ngform"` is not needed, unless you're using it for something else as well.